# Oracle EXTRACTVALUE function with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to use "GROUP BY" function on the column "Product", I appreciate your support!

```
  SELECT  count(L.CHANNEL_ID) as "Channel Name"   ,  
  EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input//Parameter2)[1]/text()') || ' ' ||   
  EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input/Body//*[@name="Parameter2"])[1]/text()') as "Product"  
  FROM TABLE1 L  , TABLE2 X   
  group by [];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the value in the `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT  COUNT(L.CHANNEL_ID) AS "Channel Name",
        EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input//Parameter2)[1]/text()' )
        || ' ' ||   
        EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input/Body//*[@name="Parameter2"])[1]/text()' )
          AS "Product"  
FROM    TABLE1 L
        CROSS JOIN TABLE2 X
GROUP BY
        EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input//Parameter2)[1]/text()' )
        || ' ' ||   
        EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input/Body//*[@name="Parameter2"])[1]/text()' );
```

Or wrap it in a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT count(CHANNEL_ID) as "Channel Name",
       "Product"
FROM   (
  SELECT  L.CHANNEL_ID,
          EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input//Parameter2)[1]/text()' )
          || ' ' ||   
          EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(X.XML_REQUEST), '(/Input/Body//*[@name="Parameter2"])[1]/text()' )
            as "Product"  
  FROM    TABLE1 L
          CROSS JOIN TABLE2 X
)
GROUP BY "Product";
```

*(Note: you probably do not want a `CROSS JOIN`, but that is what your query does with a legacy comma join.)*

Comment: Thanks! what if I want to use the function "count" instead of "group by" on the extracted value ?

Comment: @iAlsunaid That does not make sense; to use an aggregation function (like `COUNT`) you have to `GROUP BY` something (assuming that you don't want to aggregate the entire result set down to a single row) so the two are both required. If you are asking about `GROUP BY channel_id` and then `COUNT("Product")` then just use the second query and swap which term you are grouping by and which you are counting. If you want something else then I'm not sure I understand what you want.